# Runtime error when training Prophet model with the latest v1.1.2 release

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, facebook-prophet

Is anyone else facing an issue while running the Prophet model after the latest v1.1.2 release?

I get the following error when executing `model.fit()`:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-1e4ae74985f6> in <module>
----> 1 model_training(top_5_aro, X_trainARO, X_validARO, df_ARO, predict_index)

<ipython-input-85-9ee9b229fcde> in model_training(list_accounts, df_train, df_validation, df_original, predict_index)
     98         model = Prophet()
     99         # fit the model
--> 100         model.fit(train_data3)
    101 
    102         # use the model to make a forecast

/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py in fit(self, df, **kwargs)
   1179             self.params = self.stan_backend.sampling(stan_init, dat, self.mcmc_samples, **kwargs)
   1180         else:
-> 1181             self.params = self.stan_backend.fit(stan_init, dat, **kwargs)
   1182 
   1183         self.stan_fit = self.stan_backend.stan_fit

/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/models.py in fit(self, stan_init, stan_data, **kwargs)
     98             # Fall back on Newton
     99             if not self.newton_fallback or args['algorithm'] == 'Newton':
--> 100                 raise e
    101             logger.warning('Optimization terminated abnormally. Falling back to Newton.')
    102             args['algorithm'] = 'Newton'

/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/models.py in fit(self, stan_init, stan_data, **kwargs)
     94 
     95         try:
---> 96             self.stan_fit = self.model.optimize(**args)
     97         except RuntimeError as e:
     98             # Fall back on Newton

/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/cmdstanpy/model.py in optimize(self, data, seed, inits, output_dir, sig_figs, save_profile, algorithm, init_alpha, tol_obj, tol_rel_obj, tol_grad, tol_rel_grad, tol_param, history_size, iter, save_iterations, require_converged, show_console, refresh, time_fmt, timeout)
    736                 get_logger().warning(msg)
    737             else:
--> 738                 raise RuntimeError(msg)
    739         mle = CmdStanMLE(runset)
    740         return mle

RuntimeError: Error during optimization! Command '/opt/app-root/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/stan_model/prophet_model.bin random seed=97108 data file=/tmp/tmplilnrs7m/fk4f5y6m.json init=/tmp/tmplilnrs7m/q_6vjmch.json output file=/tmp/tmplilnrs7m/prophet_model1ny0mums/prophet_model-20230125181922.csv method=optimize algorithm=newton iter=10000' failed
```

I did not have this issue in the previous version. Any help appreciated!

Python version: 3.8.3
Prophet version: 1.1.2

When using the earlier version I was successfully able to train the model and view the model predictions. After upgrading to the latest v1.1.2 of prophet, I face this error when training the model.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Have you figured out a way to fix it?